# Exchanging a Dropbox authorization code for a re-useable access token with php and oauth2

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, authorization, dropbox, access-token

I am trying to exchange the authorization code I received without success. I am using the manual way where I omit the redirect url:

```
https://api.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<key>scope=&state=<state>
```

when this url is activated it will take the user to the authorization screen, if the user authorized the app, it DOES NOT redirect, instead it prints an authorization code such as:

> ```
> Enter this code into <app-name> to finish the process.
>
> GooKWtwe54AAAAAAABABSUl_Ruv1COvpBBCuWQ5kv2g
> ```

How do I exchange this code for an access token?

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/Exchange-the-authorization-code-for-a-re-useable-access-token/m-p/194306#M8775 ]

Answer (score 1):

If you're not supplying a `redirect_uri` parameter on /oauth2/authorize to automatically redirect the user, you can prompt them to copy that authorization code into your app manually. Then, your app should exchange that authorization code for an access token using /oauth2/token.

Also, note that /oauth2/authorize should be accessed on www.dropbox.com not api.dropboxapi.com, as it is a web page. The /oauth2/token endpoint is an API call, so that should called on api.dropboxapi.com.

You can find the documentation for both of these here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#authorization

Comment: Greg, you are a genius. Sometimes the issue is so small it is easily overlooked! 

FYI, the problem was in:

- https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/token
+ https://api.dropbox.com/oauth2/token